# Implementing Gmail Tablet like Navigation Drawer

Tags: android, gmail, navigation-drawer, tablet, material-design

I was looking into the tablet design of Gmail application. In that `Navigation Drawer` implementation is different from others. I have attached image for your reference.

[image]

And also when I expand the the drawer it should happen like normal navigation drawer behavior.

[image]

I would like to implement in the same way. I was searching but i found only this [link](https://medium.com/sebs-top-tips/material-navigation-drawer-sizing-558aea1ad266) Which is not so helpful. Can anyone give me suggestions how can I do this!

Comment: you can use sliding panel for it,http://www.incredibleandros.com/slidingpanel-android-example/

Comment: @TusharPandey Thanks for your reply. It's my mistake i didn't explain the question properly before. Now I have edited it again. I want the behavior to be similar like Navigation Drawer. Please consider the second image and help me out.

Comment: this is new material design ToolBar with navigation drawer ,https://chris.banes.me/2014/10/17/appcompat-v21/

Comment: But tool bar is entirely different from how it implemented in Gmail app for Tablet. How can it be a toolbar? I know what toolbar is and i have implemented them. But I feel it cannot be achieved using toolbar by toolbar by any mean. If you are so sure about using toolbar can u please explain more?

Comment: Are you talking about navigation drawer, Custom navigation drawer.

Comment: I think you didn't get my question. It a custom navigation drawer. But what i want is when i close the drawer i want it like first image when i open i want it like second image. This is what I'm trying to implement. Hope you get it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use a `SlidingPaneLayout` with a margin on the main pane and custom listener for the cross fading.

```
<com.sqisland.android.CrossFadeSlidingPaneLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/sliding_pane_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
  <FrameLayout
      android:layout_width="240dp"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:background="@color/purple">
  <TextView
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:text="@string/full"/>
  <TextView
      android:layout_width="64dp"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:background="@color/blue"
      android:text="@string/partial"/>
  </FrameLayout>
  <TextView
      android:layout_width="400dp"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:layout_weight="1"
      android:layout_marginLeft="64dp"
      android:background="@color/light_blue"
      android:text="@string/pane_2"/>
</com.sqisland.android.CrossFadeSlidingPaneLayout>
```

Subclass `SlidingPaneLayout` and find the partial and full panes in `onFinishInflate`:

```
protected void onFinishInflate() {
  super.onFinishInflate();

  if (getChildCount() < 1) {
    return;
  }

  View panel = getChildAt(0);
  if (!(panel instanceof ViewGroup)) {
    return;
  }

  ViewGroup viewGroup = (ViewGroup) panel;
  if (viewGroup.getChildCount() != 2) {
    return;
  }
  fullView = viewGroup.getChildAt(0);
  partialView = viewGroup.getChildAt(1);

  super.setPanelSlideListener(crossFadeListener);
}
```

Change the alpha of the full pane and partial pane with a listener:

```
private SimplePanelSlideListener crossFadeListener 
    = new SimplePanelSlideListener() {
  public void onPanelSlide(View panel, float slideOffset) {
    super.onPanelSlide(panel, slideOffset);
    if (partialView == null || fullView == null) {
      return;
    }

    partialView.setVisibility(isOpen() ? View.GONE : VISIBLE);
    partialView.setAlpha(1 - slideOffset);
    fullView.setAlpha(slideOffset);
  }
};
```

Also, hide the partial pane when the layout is opened.

```
protected void onLayout(
    boolean changed, int l, int t, int r, int b) {
  super.onLayout(changed, l, t, r, b);

  if (partialView != null) {
    partialView.setVisibility(isOpen() ? View.GONE : VISIBLE);
  }
}
```

More info: http://blog.sqisland.com/2015/01/partial-slidingpanelayout.html

Comment: Appreciate this answer. The blog helped me how exactly they have implemented. Thanks a lot @chiuki

Answer (score 2):

There is an awesome library for this
https://github.com/mikepenz/MaterialDrawer

(Use MiniDrawer from this library)

Comment: that project is for Android Studio , and i want to implement it in eclipse so ll you please help me ?

Comment: @VaishaliSutariya Eclipse is deprecated for Android Development. So it will be better to move to Android Studio