# How to enable or fake mini variant from Material Design guide for android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout?

Tags: android, android-layout, material-design, android-navigation, android-drawer

How to enable the "mini variant" from the [Material Design guide](http://www.google.com/design/spec/patterns/navigation-drawer.html#navigation-drawer-behavior) - so that only the Drawer icons are shown in its closed state?

[image: mini variant]

As [a simple test project](https://github.com/afarber/android-newbie/tree/q34/NavigationDrawerExample) for my question I have taken the well-known [Navigation Drawer Example by Google](https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html) - and then added the second Drawer on the right side and icons for the ListView entries on both sides:

[image: screenshot]

[image: screenshot]

Please advise how to activate (or maybe fake?) the "mini variant Drawer" - so that only the music symbols are visible on the right side of the above screenshot.

Here is my layout file [activity_main.xml](https://github.com/afarber/android-newbie/blob/q34/NavigationDrawerExample/res/layout/activity_main.xml):

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout 
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar 
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ImageView 
            android:src="@drawable/ic_music_note_black_24dp"
            android:onClick="openActions"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:padding="16dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/content_frame"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/right_drawer"
        android:layout_width="160dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="end"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

And the [MainActivity.java](https://github.com/afarber/android-newbie/blob/q34/NavigationDrawerExample/src/com/example/android/navigationdrawerexample/MainActivity.java) using it:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private Toolbar mToolbar;
    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    private ListView mDrawerList;
    private ListView mActionList;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;

    private String[] mPlanetTitles;
    private String[] mActions;
    private int[] mIcons;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mPlanetTitles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.planets_array);
        mActions = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.music_actions);

        TypedArray ta = getResources().obtainTypedArray(R.array.music_icons);
        mIcons = new int[ta.length()];
        for (int i = 0; i < mIcons.length; i++)
            mIcons[i] = ta.getResourceId(i, R.drawable.ic_menu_black_24dp);
        ta.recycle();

        mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);

        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);
        mActionList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.right_drawer);

        mDrawerList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            R.layout.drawer_list_item, mPlanetTitles) {
            @Override
            public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                TextView view = (TextView) super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
                view.setCompoundDrawablePadding(24);
                view.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(
                    R.drawable.ic_stars_white_24dp, 0, 0, 0);
                return view;
            }
        });

        mActionList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, mActions) {
            @Override
            public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                TextView view = (TextView) super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
                view.setCompoundDrawablePadding(24);
                view.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(mIcons[position], 0, 0, 0);
                return view;
            }
        });

        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this,                  /* host Activity */
                mDrawerLayout,         /* DrawerLayout object */
                mToolbar,
                R.string.drawer_open,  /* "open drawer" description for accessibility */
                R.string.drawer_close  /* "close drawer" description for accessibility */
                ) {
            public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
                mToolbar.setTitle(mTitle);
                invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to onPrepareOptionsMenu()
            }

            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                mToolbar.setTitle(mDrawerTitle);
                invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to onPrepareOptionsMenu()
            }
        };
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            selectItem(0);
        }
    }
```

Here is [a video showing Gmail for tablets](https://youtu.be/mlG79RmZ3zw) in this mode.

Comment: Could you please describe the desired behaviour more explicitely? (Is the mini drawer always visible? What transition should be used when you slide the drawer away? ...)

Comment: Yes, always visible: either icons only (closed drawer) or same icons and text (when the drawer is opened). Transition does not matter as long as you don't just toggle visibility of 2 different drawers.

Comment: this can be seen in the Gmail app on Tablets. I hope it will be a part of NavigationView with design support library. see http://www.google.co.in/design/spec/patterns/navigation-drawer.html#navigation-drawer-behavior

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The official **NavigationDrawer** does indeed mention 'mini-variant' in their [design specification](http://www.google.com/design/spec/patterns/navigation-drawer.html#navigation-drawer-behavior), but there is no documentation of how to use it. Maybe it will come later as a part of support library. Will update the answer if / when there will be an official solution.

Until than, take a look at [ActionsContentView library](https://github.com/StevenRudenko/ActionsContentView), does exactly what you want. Last time it was updates was 2 years ago, but it works, I have used it a while ago. You can also get it on [Google Play](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=sample.actionscontentview) and test it.

[image: Closed state]
[image: Opened state]

Answer (score 4):

Please visit following link:

https://github.com/mikepenz/MaterialDrawer

https://github.com/mikepenz/MaterialDrawer/issues/487

MaterialDrawer is an implementation to create material drawer. Its latest version, 4.0, though not released yet, provides an "**embedded drawer**" to reach what you want. Not perfect until now because I've downloaded its demo, tried this new feature and found the drawer couldn't open by sliding, but the author are working hard to finish it.

As a result, you can wait for the soon release and check its usage at that time.

Answer (score 2):

Check out this other Mini nav variant question: [Implementing Gmail Tablet like Navigation Drawer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27400061/implementing-gmail-tablet-like-navigation-drawer). 
It appears to have a working solution for the Mini nav drawer variant just as it's found in the Gmail app for tablets as @Amol Gupta mentioned. The accepted answer in the other question contains a link to a [blog post](http://blog.sqisland.com/2015/01/partial-slidingpanelayout.html) with a more detailed explanation on how to implement the mini variant. Their solution uses a Sliding Pane Layout that cross-fades between a "partial" layout and a "full" layout.

Here's a link to the example source of the blog post as well:
https://github.com/chiuki/sliding-pane-layout

Answer (score 0):

I'll recommend to change the `layout_width` of `@id/left_drawer` from `240dp` to a smaller number, like `80dp`.